# Changing default page size for Printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I have a vb.net application that uses 2 crystal reports to print out reports. The first report is A4 and the second is A5.

How can my code access the printer default settings and change the default paper size to A4 and A5 each time without having to do it manually.

Thanks

Comment: I have never been able to figure it out.  Part of the problem is that Crystal is dependent on the printers installed on the machine you're developing Crystal from so when you want to change a page size it conforms you to what you have available (which is kind frustrating because you can take that report, move it to a computer that doesn't have that printer and still run it).  In order to get long width pages sometimes you have to install drivers for printers you don't really have and use those since Crystal will then think you do have them.  I've found no way to do this through code though.

Comment: Take a look at "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PrintOptions" and the PrintOptions variable off of the report and see what's available there.  Another similiar question:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1437563.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

This worked but not with MS Word:

```
 Dim pp As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
        For i = 0 To pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
            If pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(i).Kind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4 Then
                pp.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```